# how to fix error given when using 'ldid' to sign cydia app

Tags: ios, jailbreak, codesign

I have used the `ldid` utility to codesign my application so it can go on to cydia. And Yes I built my app with the `armv7` set.

Here is the code I used within the terminal:

```
/// Before running the below code, I connected to my iDevice using SSH

root# ldid -S /Applications/(appname here).app/(appname here)

/// Here is the error
util/ldid.cpp(567): _assert(0:arch != NULL)
```

Does anyone have any ideas on fixing this error?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be popping up quite randomly. What I tend to do to resolve the problem:

1. Delete the binary (**both** from the app bundle and from the build directory!)
2. Re-compile, re-link the source to produce a new binary
3. Retry. If the error persists, then repeat step 1., 2., then **remove** the fake codesign using `ldid -s <binary>` (note the lowercase `s`), then retry.

Comment: how do i go about deleting the binary

Comment: @TheCODER999 Just like you would delete any other file.

Comment: what is the binary called

Comment: @TheCODER999 Whatever you named it. (***Please, please, pretty please, use punctuation!***)

Comment: I'm sorry but that does not work for me

Comment: @TheCODER999 "does not work" is not informative.